# how can we set Height of list view in java file?

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am fetching data for List View from web and want to set Height of List View according to data no of elements in List View are not fix, so I am trying below code but its gives error at run time, so any one can help me to solve this problem, thanks

you can see my xml file here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sos_scroll"
    android:layout_above="@+id/last_lin" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sos_rel" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:scrollbars="none"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/list" android:dividerHeight="2dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date" android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false" android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@drawable/newshape_list"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dip" android:paddingRight="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:fadingEdge="none" android:divider="#A9ABAD"></ListView>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list">
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/add_table" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/listback" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/add_data">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/addbuttonimage" android:id="@+id/que1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:text="Add New Stress..."
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                        android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dip" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/last_lin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="52dip" android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/done" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="Save"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/savebutton"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

error is here

```
08-22 11:00:34.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1291)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1238)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:279)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:299)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:893)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:276)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:569)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:361)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at  android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:569)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:361)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-22 11:00:34.959: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(324):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Perhaps specifying the error that you get at runtime would help?

Comment: need more code, specially xml codes.It looks like error not related to listview.It is related to some layout in your xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about creating your ListView completely dynamically? In other words, try programmatically creating your ListView, and then manually add it to your layout.

Also, is there any reason in particular that you want to specify the ListView height manually?  Your ListView will automatically resize itself anyway depending on the amount of data you have, and if you have more data than that could fit on the screen, it will become scrollable.

### Edit

In reference to your second comment and your included XML layout, here's what I suggest you do.

Your XML file should only have one root element (hence why it's called the root). Currently, you have a ScrollView and a LinearLayout. I suggest you just use a LinearLayout as the root. You can use this as a rough skeleton:

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  ... >

    <ListView
        ...
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TableLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
    <Button
        ...
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout basically pushes your Button to the very bottom, and your TableLayout to the bottom, but above the Button. Your ListView will take the rest of the space above the the TableLayout. (By the way, a TableRow is basically a specialized LinearLayout. You can simply replace the TableLayout with a horizontal LinearLayout to achieve similar results, unless you plan to add multiple rows to the table and need equal sizing for the columns.)

Comment: ok that is true but when set Height of list View wrap_content i found just one item in List View what is the reason for this can you describe please?

Comment: It may help if you described what kind of layout you were trying to get. For example, are you trying to do something where a ListView takes up as much space as possible, without pushing bottom elements off the screen? Also, are you saying that your ListView has only one item, but if you scroll, you find several more? Or is there really just one item? Finally, it would be easier for us to figure out your problem if you posted the rest of your XML layout.

Comment: ok i am pasting full Xml file I have a table layout exactly bellow List view and it should be remain below to List View and List view should be expand according to List data

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect my suggestions based on your comment.